# converting an array of integers into one long integer

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I need to write a program to receive a number from the user, use a user=defined method to reverse the number, then return the number as an integer. Below is what I have so far. I am trying to see if I can take each individual digit from the array and somehow put them together as an integer. Do I need to put them together as a string and then convert it to integer? or is there a simpler way all together to do this?

```
import java.util.*;

public class UserDefinedMethods
{
  static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   public static int reverseDigits(int num)
   {
     int reverse[];
     int i = 0;
     int out = 0;
     do
     {
      if (num < 0)
         num = (num * -1);

         reverse[i] = num % 10;
         num = num/10;
         i++;
      }
   while (num > 0);
      out = 
   return reverse; //HERE IS MY PROBLEM I BELEIVE.
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     int number = 0;
     int output = 0;
     System.out.println("Please enter a number:");
     number = keyboard.nextInt(); 
     output = reverseDigits(number);
     System.out.println(output);
   }
}
```

Comment: Edit the question. Paste code at bottom of question. Select the code. Press ctrl-k. Remember to save.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was hitting ctrl-k and then trying to paste in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reversing an `int` can be done as follows:

1. Set `result` to zero.
2. If the number is zero, return the result that you have so far
3. Add a trailing zero to the result
4. Replace trailing zero with the last digit of the original number
5. Drop the last digit of the original number
6. Go to step 2.

Here is how to do selected things in Java:

- To get the last digit use `int lastDigit = number % 10;`
- To drop the last digit use `number /= 10;`
- To add zero as the last digit of the result use `result *= 10;`
- To replace the trailing last digit use `result += lastDigit;`

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/933fjT)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. I mean my code reverses the number and inputs it one digit at a time into the reverse array. But I don't see how to go from there.

Comment: @ethancodes My point is that you don't need `reverse` at all. Replace it with `out *= 10; out += num % 10;`

Comment: Oh of course! Now I see! Much simpler than what I was thinking! Thank you!

Comment: Oh see! Sorry! I'm still new to this site.

Answer (score 0):

Ok first off, you're attempting to return the array reverse, but your method declaration is set to return an int (not int[]). Secondly, your code can be simplified as follows:

```
public static int reverseDigits(int num){
    int reverse = 0;
    while(num != 0){
        reverse *= 10;
        reverse += (num % 10);
        num /= 10;
    }
    return reverse;
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I didn't see the last half dasblinkenlight's answer. Sorry for the duplicate post.